# Checkout Page too slow - Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1

I'm trying to figure out why my checkout page is too slow, sometimes gives timeout, and sometimes after loading for minutes it works.

**Few important things:**

My platform is in production mode. Checked.

Server settings:

Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz

CPUs: 8

RAM Memory: 8 Gb

HD: 160 Gb

Network: 800Mbs

Apache with PHP 5.6 and Varnish (Only for HTTP not for Checkout that uses HTTPS).

Is there anything wrong with it?

Thanks.

Comment: This likely isn't a hardware performance problem. There has been several problems like this described in github's M2 repo. Are you using Authorize.net for payment processing?